# How can I create a unique id from a network using Java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, uuid, mac-address

Suppose I have two networks, A and B, and I have ten clients, five on each network, and I wanted to be able to pseudo-anonymously distinguish which clients are on which network. The networks are connected to the internet, each client generates a unique ID for the machine that it's on, and the server that the IDs are sent to is not on either network.

I currently can generate unique ids for each client machine using the mac address as follows:

```
public UUID generateClientId() {
    byte[] macAddress;
    try {
        final InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        final NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        macAddress = network.getHardwareAddress();
    } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (final SocketException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(macAddress);
}
```

This information, however, does not tell me which client machine is on which network. How would I create an ID for the network that, when sent in conjunction with the clientId, would allow me to tell which network the client machines belong to?

Does a solution exist that would allow the unique identification of any number of networks running the client?

**Edit**
It seems that I have confused people with the code block that I posted. Please disregard it. I was trying to make it clear that that code will *not* accomplish what I am looking for.

Goal:
I want to know whether requests that the server receives are coming from the same place, and how many requests are coming from that place.

For example:
Alice, Bob, and Mary are at Steve's house and on Steve's wifi network. They are all using the client (where the ID generating code lives). I want a way to know that there are four unique users making requests from Steve's wifi network. When Alice goes home, she uses the client from her wifi network and I want to know that there is one user making requests from Alice's network.

All of this data will be anonymized because I do not care about who they are. I only care about the number of networks that use the client, and number of people on those networks. Double counting Alice is OK because she is on a different network. So in the example, there are two networks with four and one user respectively. That is what I want to know.

Comment: What is the problem you want to actually solve?

Comment: could you make an ID which would use the id generation from the mac adress you wrote in combinaison to the ID of the network where the client connects to ? networkId-clientId => i know who is where

Comment: MAC addresses (a) are not necessarily unique across multiple networks and (b) are not fixed.

Comment: The MAC addresses would be unique in conjunction with the network, no? I want to know if I can uniquely identify the network from which the client makes requests to the server.

Comment: @GavinKillough What does "uniquely identify the network" mean to you?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Traffic coming through the same modem to access the internet would be considered a "unique" network. 

Forgive me, my knowledge of networking is not great, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @GavinKillough The reason I ask as I do is because it is unclear if the solution you present in your question is solving the problem you have.  I would suggest that you rethink what it is you _really_ need to know (and why) and edit your question to present that as clearly as you possibly can.

Comment: I have updated the question to (hopefully) give a better idea of what I would like to accomplish.